# Create a statement in propositional logic. This statment must have 2 attributes. (The attributes are specified in the top header)

Tags: logic, propositions

### The following are the 2 attributes: (1) This statement claims the statement after it is true. (2) This statement cannot be not true.

This statement would achieve these 2 attributes through its wording. This statement cannot be false because if it were false; it would either generator a paradox, or break the rules of propositional logic.

Yes, it will be very difficult (although I suspect the answer will be simplistic, like all answers to difficult formal language questions). But, please only post an answer if you have created a statement that acts in the way described in the title. If you don't think it can be done, then please either post a comment or don't be involved in this post at all. For those who think this is impossible, consider Liar Statements (AKA "This statement is false"). Liar Statements seemed impossible to exist, until they were discovered.

Everything below is not part of the question, however it provides useful information.

> (((The following statement is false)v(The following statement is true.))v(The following statement is undefined))
>
> The truth table for (((The following statement is false)v(The following statement is true.))v(The following statement is undefined)) would obviously be the same as the truth table for ((AvB)vC).
>
> [image: Truth table for ((AvB)vC)]
>
> According to the axioms of propositional logic, a statement must be either true, false, or undefined. Therefore, the logic table would actually be the following. Because A, B, and C could not all be false.
>
> [image: Revised Truth table for ((AvB)vC]

Keelan come up with the statement "True is true." "True is true," is a statement that has the 2nd attribute, but not the 1st attribute.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this like a logic version of code-golf or a legitimate question about logic?

Comment: @virmaior Both.

Comment: Okay, what specifically is the question you have about logic that someone can help you with?

Comment: @virmaior If a statement meeting this criteria has already been invented, then the question is "What is that type of statement called?" If the statement has not yet been invented, then its a logic version of code-golf.

Comment: Meeting which criteria exactly? This post does not clarify it any further than "act in the same way described in the title." Would "True" be a correct answer, since then "True is True" would be the consequent of that implication, hence the implication is always true? Please clarify what you mean by [edit]ing your question (it would also be a good idea to leave out irrelevant text for brevity), then it can be reopened.

Comment: @Keelan (1) "True is true" would be the correct answer. However I realized that this couldn't be used for making other statement's true (and that's what I'm really after). I edited the question accordingly. (2) I don't know how to clarify this any more than it is. The only thing I can think of is to restate instead of saying "act in the same way described," but that goes against the other thing you said "leave out irrelevant text for brevity."

Comment: Sorry, but I still have no idea what is being asked here. The second sentence of your title is ungrammatical. With "irrelevant text" I was pointing primarily at putting this into a challenge format and the gangster alternative formulation. They distract from the actual content, which is still unclear.

Comment: @Keelan I edited the question, is that better? You, Keelan, created a statement with the 2nd attribute (True is true.). So are you just confused about the 1st attribute?

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you're getting at now. I don't think such a statement exists. In fact, you can prove that it doesn't. If such a statement, say P, would exist, then it would hold that P -> Q (where Q is the following statement). Furthermore, P most hold. However, P -> Q is false when P is true and Q is false. So, such a statement P cannot exist, because the following statement might be false and that contradicts either the first or the second attribute.

Comment: @Keelan Why would the statements need to be connected with Material Implication? The idea of the question is P's existence means that Q cannot be false (without causing a paradox or breaking the rules of propositional logic).

Comment: But that is a restriction on Q, not on P, and you want it to work for any Q.

Comment: @Keelan What restriction are you referring to? (If you're referring to material implication, I'm saying that the statements might not be connected through material implication. They might be connected through a logic operator that doesn't exist. Like my smiley face operator I created, before deleting it after I realized it was unneeded information.)

Comment: @user235979 I'm referring to "This statements claims the statement after it true."

Comment: @Keelan I think we might be using different definitions of true and false. I mean true and false in the same way as positive and negative in math. External circumstances don't determine whether a number or equation is positive or negative. However, obviously there are differences between math and propositional logic (the major difference being that propositional logic uses words), but there are basically no differences between "true and positive" and "false and negative." A true statement means that it isn't the opposite of what the statment says (like a positive number). (continued)

Comment: @Keelan (continued) And a false statement means that it is the opposite of what the statement says (like a negative number).

Comment: This is better, but "axioms of propositional logic" do not say anything about "true", "false" or "undefined", they are just formulas. And in semantics one can work with more than three truth values, or allow truth gaps and/or true contradictions. "The next sentence is true. The previous sentence is false" is a [form of Liar paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%27s_paradox). On [truth gap interpretations](http://www.iep.utm.edu/par-liar/#H2) both sentences are neither true nor false, so technically they meet your conditions.

Comment: But 37 is always positive, no matter what statement you put in front of it, and so "false" is false no matter what statement you put in front of it.

Comment: @Conifold (1) What do you mean by "just formulas"? I would think propositional logic's axioms would discuss true, false, and maybe undefined. What is propositional logic without true and false. The answer is plain regular English. (2) In looking at examples claiming to be more than only "true", "false", or "undefined", I haven't seen any convincing examples, I think the examples are just more difficult to comprehend. I thought "undefined" defines anything that isn't 100% true or 100% false. (continued)

Comment: @Conifold (continued) (3) I don't see how "The next sentence is true. The previous sentence is false," satisfies the 2nd attribute (which is the tricky one).

Comment: @Keelan Well I could add a negative to the "37", rendering "37" to -37 instead of adding a positive, rendering "37" to "+37". In math it is assumed that a number without any sign is a positive number (for efficiency and ease of reading). So when one says "37" they really mean "+37".

Comment: But then it's not the same number / statement any more.

Comment: As I said before, you are using "propositional logic" in some personal sense, which is unclear, here are [standard axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_1._Simple_axiom_system). Classical semantics for it is two-valued, so no "undefined", but it can also be interpreted on any Boolean algebra with 2^n truth values. [Three-valued logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) are non-classical, classical propositional logic can not be interpreted on them. You'll have to figure out your framework before your question becomes well-posed.

Comment: From what I understand, we imagine two statements, **S1** and **S2**, s.th. (a) **S1** claims that **S2** is true and (b) **S1** is necessarily true. But what’s **S2**? Do we get to pick that in advance, before searching for an appropriate **S1**? (If so, just make **S2** a tautology and let **S1** = ‘**S2** is true’.) Or is the task to find an **S1** that satisfies (a) and (b) *no matter what* **S2** is? That seems impossible: given any false **S2**, **S1** can’t meet (a) and still be true. (I may just be echoing the point @Keelan made, on Oct 22 at 20:20).